# To "resign in disgrace"

Tags: meaning, expressions

What does "in disgrace" mean in the following headlines?

- "Keith O’Brien, Catholic cardinal who resigned in disgrace, dies at 80"
- "President Nixon Resigns in Disgrace"

Comment: This term is generally used when someone has to step back from a position/designation because people don't approve of them. 
for example -"Keith O'Brian" had to resign as Archbishop because he was involved in a sexual misconduct.

Comment: Did you look up "disgrace" in a dictionary?

Comment: Honestly, I did.

Comment: But ELU requires that results of relevant research be included, Sebastian. [Collins CoBuild](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/to%20be%20in%20disgrace) gives almost your exact sentence. Other dictionaries might point out that 'in disgrace' might be seen as a depictive here (pointing to the state of the person when they resigned rather than really modifying the verb).

Answer (score 0):

If people resign in disgrace, they give up their job or position because their reputation is destroyed by some dishonourable action. In other words, they leave disgracefully.